# python coverage no source for code (builtin)

Tags: python, coverage.py

What I did is:

```
coverage run --source=HelloCNN1 test_hellocnn1.py
coverage run --source=HelloCNN2 test_hellocnn2.py
coverage combine
coverage report -m --skip-empty
```

The error output:

```
(base) zz@home% coverage report -m --skip-empty                  
No source for code: '/home/zz/work/cnn/tests/(builtin)'.
Aborting report output, consider using -i.
```

Wondering how can I "ignore (buitin)"?

Comment: Try running with `-i` as suggested. You can ignore files/dirs with `--omit`, but Im not sure if that works for this case. https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/cmd.html#reporting

Comment: I'd be curious what is claiming to be "(builtin)"... I haven't seen that before.